# How to load users in Keycloak from my application database?

Tags: mysql, laravel, keycloak

I have a laravel application with a mysql db that has a users table with email and encrypted password.

I want to setup keycloak for authentication of frontend(standalone vue application).

I could set up keycloak with a mysql database, however how can I make keycloak use the laravel's users table, since I'll be creating new users in the user's table.

Answer (score 0):

Either you have to implement an [Custom User Storage Provider](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1UklqPPjcRY) or you synchronize  your application with keycloak by using the keycloak user API.